# Setting up Python in Netbeans

Tags: python, netbeans, python-3.x

I remember successfully doing this countless times before with a bit of trial and error, but after a new reinstall of Snow Leopard, I would like to just ask the Stackoverflow community this for once and for all...

I installed Netbeans 7 (for C++). For some reason, I didn't see any way to install Python plugins here, so I installed Netbeans 6.5. It automatically detects Python 2.5 on the system, but darnit I want Python 3, which it cannot automatically detect. So now I go to Tools > Python Platforms, click on New, and which file do I select in the new window?

EDIT: I found this when looking in `usr/bin/`.[image]

EDIT: For my own future reference, in Eclipse  at least, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

I found the alias in `.../3.2/bin/python3.2`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately Netbeans seem to have dropped support for Python in version 7. I find it pretty annoying as it seems to work ok in 6.9.1 (although I resort to Eclipse for serious Python programming as PyDev has better code completion).

So, your options are

- Download 6.9.1, and get the python plugin via tools--> plugins

or

- Attempt to hack the previous version plugin together with version 7, as described here:
  http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic38275.html
  and here http://forums.netbeans.org/topic37805.html - I've copied in the appropriate post below. The forum mentions code completion causing crashes, so YMMV.

To summarise the forum post:
"Just go to Tools->Plugins, click Settings. Click Add, and add a new "Update Center" , name it like "Python plugin is here", and in the link, paste this:

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz

Then go to Avaliable Plugins, do "Reload Catalog" - you should see stuff under "category" Python. Select the plugin and click install. Netbeans will ask you to restart itself. Then you should see Python under installed plugins (make sure to click "Show Details" there.)"

Comment: The solution here of adding the "deadlock" updates to the plugin repos is widely suggested - eg at http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall - it is key to know that this will cause Netbeans to be updated to the "dev" release. Reports are that this is stable, but I can't confirm them YMMV. Personally I'm looking for a more supported/stable suggestion.

Comment: It may be worth noting that I used to work with Netbeans / Eclipse Pydev **before** Pycharm released a free community edition, which I currently judge better supported than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you have to be running the Dev version of Netbeans for the python plugin to be available.  Tools>Plugins>Available Plugins.

This Netbeans forum topic has the steps:
http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=104025

Comment: By the way, where do I get the developer version of Netbeans?

Answer (score -1):

Your python 3.1 binary. I'm not familiar with OSX but usually it would be something like `/usr/bin/python3.1`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any python3 stuff in that folder unfortunately, as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Do you actually have python 3.1 installed globally?

Comment: what do you mean by globally? I just used the Python installer, can use IDLE